# Firemonkey - Tips for Positioning Components in Mobile Applications

Tags: android, delphi, android-layout, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

As far as I understand, in Delphi for Android I set width and height of a component in pixels. Therefore it will be perceptible difference on various screens. I wish there were a method for setting size in [dp units](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence) instead (or smth similar).

```
ActionBar: TToolBar;

ActionBar := TToolBar.Create(Form1);
ActionBar.Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
ActionBar.Height := 30.0;
ActionBar.Parent := Form1;
```

As you can see I set up dimensions manually. The reason why I refused to use layouts is that I mix FMX with native Android components.
I want my Action Bar to look beautiful on various screens:) What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: Could you use a percentage of the form height/width?

Comment: @MikeSutton, the best I thought for today is to calculate dp constants. According to the Android Dev Guide `px = dp * (dpi / 160);`, `dp = px / (dpi / 160);`. Just now I found `dp := px * SharedActivityContext.getResources.getDisplayMetrics.density;`

Answer (score 2):

I use layouts to put in every component. I make rows of layouts and don't set size for anything, but you need to aling it. So for example if you have a form with 10 rows of labels and edits. Add 10 layouts and align them to top, then add a label in the layout and align it left and add a edit and align it all client. This way all compontents will resize properly!

Checkout this link for more info:
[Layouts](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Mobile_Tutorial%3a_Using_Layout_to_Adjust_Different_Form_Sizes_or_Orientations_%28iOS_and_Android%29)

Answer (score -1):

I uses Tlayout and its variations. I hit the same problem and the only way I could solve it is. If you want other information Google the term Delphi Responsive. A good day.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers here should be useful and complete, and not include links only or suggestions for googling terms. Please edit your answers to contain the relevant information.